# How to start editing contenteditable at clicked position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, contenteditable

Report designer contains editable, resizable and draggable fields.

Clicking in field places cursor to start of field end editing start alway at beginning of field.
How to place cursor in field to clicked position so that editing start at clicked position ?

jquery, jquery ui, bootstarp, ASP.NET MVC4 are used.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
    .panel-resizable {
      min-height: 1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .panel {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .verticalline,
    .horizontalline,
    .rectangle {
      font-size: 1pt;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
    .field {
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      white-space: pre;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .captionfield {
      white-space: pre;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .field,
    .captionfield {
      font-family: "Times New Roman";
      font-size: 10pt;
    }
    .verticalline {
      border-left-style: none !important;
    }
    .horizontalline {
      border-bottom-style: none !important;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".panel-resizable").resizable({
        minWidth: "100%",
        maxWidth: "100%",
        minHeight: 1
      });
      $(".verticalline, .horizontalline, .rectangle, .field, .image, .captionfield").draggable();
      $(".verticalline, .horizontalline, .rectangle, .field, .image").resizable();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable'>
      <div class='field' contenteditable='true'>IR(&quot;Kreedit arvele nr. &quot;)+iif( isnull(g_server),&#39;&#39;,psql(&#39;select tasudok from dok x where dokumnr= ?dok.krdokumnr&#39;))</div>
      <div class='field' contenteditable='true'>IR(&quot;Kreedit arvele nr. &quot;)+ iif( isnull(g_server), sql(&#39;sele tasudok from dok x where doktyyp+str(dokumnr,7)= &quot;G&quot;+str(dok.krdokumnr,7) &#39;,&#39;&#39;),psql(&#39;select tasudok from dok where dokumnr= ?dok.krdokumnr&#39;))</div>
      <div class='field' contenteditable='true'>vnimi+&#39; &#39;+dok.tasudok</div>
      <div class='field' contenteditable='true'>DOK.kuupaev</div>
    </div>
    <div class='bg-warning'>
      <div class='panel-footer'>GroupHeader 1: str(dokumnr)+str(koopia,2)</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```